# Rails 4 how to merge 2 arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 arrays filled with information provided by sql queries.
My first array is Reviews array will return this JSON object:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "score": 4,
      "comment": "Probably some comment",
      "first_name": "Doe",
      "id": 1
    }
 ]
```

}

The second one is Cleaners array which have to return this json:

```
{
      "response": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "authentication_id": 3,
          "first_name": "Consuela",
          "last_name": "Ernandez",
          "avg_rating": 3,
          "postcode": "AX13D2",
          "created_at": "2015-08-05T10:39:28.957Z",
          "updated_at": "2015-08-05T10:49:59.509Z",
          "phone_number": "Consueala's phone number",
          "status": "approved",
          "is_ok_with_pets": true
        }
```

So far so good but the final result which i have to get is merge those two arrays and render result and add avg rating for every cleaner:

```
    {
      "response": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "authentication_id": 3,
          "first_name": "Consuela",
          "last_name": "Ernandez",
          "postcode": "AX13D2",
          "avg_rating": 3,
          "created_at": "2015-08-05T10:39:28.957Z",
          "updated_at": "2015-08-05T10:49:59.509Z",
          "phone_number": "Consueala's phone number",
          "status": "approved",
          "is_ok_with_pets": true
          "reviews": [
                {
              "score": 4,
              "comment": "Probably some comment",
              "first_name": "Doe",
              "id": 1
                  }
                ]
              }
           }
```

Comment: looks like `"id": 2` disappeared in the process

Comment: more generally I guess you have serializers to create the json, why dont you do this at this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Cleaner` has_many `Review`, then you can do:

```
Cleaner.includes(:reviews).find(yourid).as_json(include: [:reviews])
```

Which will provide a json as you wanted. You can use `to_json` with same options to get directly a string.

If you want to include `avg_rating` for each cleaner, I suggest the following approach:

```
class Cleaner < ActiveRecord::Base

  def avg_rating
    # yourlogic
  end

  def as_json(**options)
    super(options.merge(methods: [:avg_rating]))
  end

end
```

Or if you want it only for that controller you can do:

```
Cleaner.includes(:reviews).find(yourid).as_json(include: [:reviews], methods: [:avg_rating])
```

Comment: No problem ;) mark it as an answer if it's right for you, so other people can find and use it

Comment: I forgot i also have to include avg rating for every cleaner

Comment: You should add it to question details

Comment: Added, sorry for that im new here :)

Comment: Please notice that if you want to get a much more granular control over what is serialized into json, I suggest you to check [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). And remember to mark the answer if it works for you